# How to set RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT with capistrano 3 on thin restart?

Tags: bundler, thin, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano, sshkit

I use capistrano 3, rvm und bundler for my deployment.

The thin server are restarted like this:

```
within release_path do
    execute :bundle, :exec, "thin restart -O -C config/thin/staging.yml"
end
```

This work fine and generate this command:

```
cd /var/www/foo/releases/20140320154611 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.0.0-p353@foo do bundle exec thin restart -O -C config/thin/staging.yml
```

Now I need to restart the thin's with this setting **RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=90000000** and I dont know how to set this up in the **execute** command?

The script has to setup rvm for knowing bundle, and RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT for thin

Not working:

1. Because rvm is not set (execute :bundle # set a rvm hook)

   execute "RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=90000000", :bundle, :exec, "thin restart -O -C config/thin/staging.yml"

2.same here

```
execute "RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=90000000 bundle exec thin restart -O -C config/thin/staging.yml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution....

```
execute :bundle, :exec, "'RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=90000000 thin restart -O -C config/thin/staging.yml'"
```